# How to fix it: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException?

Tags: java, sql-server

I want to connect to sql server express. 
I downloaded [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774) driver.
I read the help file and this is my code:

```
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=ActorsDb;integratedSecurity=true;";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Actors(FirstName,LastName,Age) VALUES(?,?,?)");
            st.setString(1, "Robert");
            st.setString(2, "de Niro");
            st.setInt(3,45);
            st.executeUpdate();     
            con.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I get this exception:`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".`

I turned off firewall but nothing changed.

1. I went to SQL Server Configuration Manager and i enabled TCP/IP
2. I went to IP Adresses, IP1 and set the properties

Active:Yes ;  Enabled:Yes ; TCP Dynamic Ports:[empty] ; TCP Port:1433

Any tips of what i am missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had to copy sqljdbc_auth.dll in the working directory.

Comment: i am trying to connect sql server with hive using sqoop  `[root@SLAVENODE1 sqoop/bin]# sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://10.23.52.15:1433;dtabase=test;username=****;password=****" --table dept -m 1 --hive-import -- --schema dbo`, the above same error occurs. I moved sqljdbc4.jar in sqoop/lib folder. As you mentioned where to copy sqljdbc_auth.dll . Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Check if the SQL Server service is running and check if any programs like anti-virus is blocking the connections. If so, disable them or add exception to that connection.

Comment: Sql server service is running because i restarted it after i made the changes. I have no antivirus program.

Answer (score 0):

You're using localhost in your JDBC URL, try instead using the IP address for "IP1" that you describe in SSCM.  Or, verify SSCM is configured to listen on localhost:1433.